# magento 2: where are methods ($_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) declared?

Tags: magento2, product, methods, object

lets say in my catalog_product_view.xml I have this additional Block:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.demo" template="product/view/warranty.phtml" after="product.info.price">
```

in warranty.phtml I use the following:

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
$_attributeValue =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

In the block class Description.php:

```
 public function getProduct()
{
    if (!$this->_product) {
        $this->_product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
    }
    return $this->_product;
}
```

We use `getProduct()` to get product object from registry.

Info: This product object was earlier first obtained and then put in the registry, in class Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product:

```
     ...       
    try {
             //productRepository is Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
            //getById() returns \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface
        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        return false;
    }
    ...
         //put obtained product object into registry
    $this->_coreRegistry->register('product', $product);
```

Method getById() in Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface:

```
     * @param int $productId
 * @param bool $editMode
 * @param int|null $storeId
 * @param bool $forceReload
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function getById($productId, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false);
```

Soo: our product-object in warranty.phtml `$_product = $block->getProduct();` should be `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface` right ?

Also: 
In warranty.phtml we call `$_attributeValue =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);` , but there are no such methods defined in \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface. Where are these methods declared/implemented ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your product object is actually an [instance of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/di.xml#L9) that [implements the product interface](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product.php#L41).
And this class contains the methods you need.

Comment: Links  are not valid please update your answer. Thanks